# A few intersecting questions about picking K elements of N

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

There are a few questions at SO that basically ask the same thing, but with slight differences:

1. [Unique (non-repeating) random numbers in O(1)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/196017/unique-non-repeating-random-numbers-in-o1/16097246?noredirect=1#comment66088726_16097246) - the most popular one, yet defines the problem badly (doesn't even introduce letters for uniformity)
2. [How do you efficiently generate a list of K non-repeating integers between 0 and an upper bound N](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/158716/how-do-you-efficiently-generate-a-list-of-k-non-repeating-integers-between-0-and-n) - defines the problem well, except it doesn't specify if it's combinations or permutations
3. [Algorithm to select a single, random combination of values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2394246/algorithm-to-select-a-single-random-combination-of-values) - the tag clearly defines it's about combinations, yet the wording is unclear about it which confuses people
4. [Efficiently selecting a set of random elements from a linked list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54059/efficiently-selecting-a-set-of-random-elements-from-a-linked-list) - the same task but specifically for linked lists

**Due to the intersections, the answers to them are a mess.**

- Answers to 1. and 2. basically address the same problem
- Some answers to 1. apply to 3. instead (that's only those I looked into in depth, there may be more)
- Several answers apply to more than one case (and occur in more than one question - or not), but to various degrees and often have deficiencies when done so - which are never specified

**Thus, as a source of knowledge on the subject, these questions as a whole are - likewise - a mess**

**Shall anything be done about this?** Maybe:

- move answers around
- merge questions / mark as a duplicate
- improve formulations in the questions to make them sound more distinct
- improve answers to add lacking details / add better copies (if the amount of work is perceived to be close enough to writing one's own answer)
- prominently link to the other questions to encourage those who have a problem better covered by another one to move there
- something else?

Comment: And the tag removal was correct—the [duplicate-answers] tag applies only to answers that are *exact* duplicates of another answer. Please read the tag excerpts before using them.

Comment: There are at least a few answers that suggest the same, I commented them accordingly. They don't need to be exact clones to a 't', as other users of the tag show (and that would be absurd to require anyway). Your formatting is not only superfluous, with it, titles won't be updated at all - and the links have been made human-readable specifically in case they become broken. Dash not being on the keyboard means it's relatively inconvenient to input which has led to hyphens being a generally accepted tradeoff in network posts, with those who aggressively "fix" them considered Grammar Nazi.

Comment: Spaces not needed - didn't know or see that, even in English texts. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dash#En_dash_versus_em_dash confirms that both versions are in general use (so yes, I was ultimately wrong to _require_ spaces). The "spaceless" version is apparently considered old-fashioned (while not yet obsolete), so I wouldn't use it in my posts anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got a general carte blanche here with no more specific ideas.

So:

- *move answers around*

  - a moderator stated this is technically impossible
- *merge questions / mark as a duplicate*

  - flagged [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/196017/unique-non-repeating-random-numbers-in-o1) as duplicate of [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/158716/how-do-you-efficiently-generate-a-list-of-k-non-repeating-integers-between-0-and-n) (**some assistance required!**)
- *improve formulations in the questions to make them sound more distinct*

  - improved [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/158716/how-do-you-efficiently-generate-a-list-of-k-non-repeating-integers-between-0-and-n) and [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2394246/algorithm-to-select-a-single-random-combination-of-values) to explicitly require permutations and combinations, respectively
- *improve answers to add lacking details / add better copies (if the amount of work is perceived to be close enough to writing one's own answer)*
- *prominently link to the other questions to encourage those who have a problem better covered by another one to move there*

  - linked [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/158716/how-do-you-efficiently-generate-a-list-of-k-non-repeating-integers-between-0-and-n) and [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2394246/algorithm-to-select-a-single-random-combination-of-values) to each other, made a link to [4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54059/efficiently-selecting-a-set-of-random-elements-from-a-linked-list) from [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/158716/how-do-you-efficiently-generate-a-list-of-k-non-repeating-integers-between-0-and-n) prominently visible
- *something else?*